# Remember active class position after page refresh with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, flickity

I'm using [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co) to implement a tab based content carousel. The below example uses the [hash script](https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity-hash). This allows uses to visit a specific tab e.g. example.com/#slide-1.

The only problem I'm having is when a user navigates to another page and goes back or refreshes the page the `is-selected` class resets itself on `tab-nav`. This means it doesn't match up to the content that's loaded.

Is there a way within javascript for the browser to remember the last `is-selected` position for when the user refreshes or goes back?

```css
.slide-content {
  width: 100%;
}

.tab-nav a,
.tab-nav a:visited,
.tab-nav a:focus,
.tab-nav a:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
}

.tab-nav .is-selected {
  background: #dedede;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity-hash@1/hash.js"></script>

<nav class="tab-nav">   
 <a class="slide is-selected" href="#slide-1">Slide One</a>
 <a class="slide" href="#slide-2">Slide Two</a>
 <a class="slide" href="#slide-3">Slide Three</a>
 <a class="slide" href="#slide-4">Slide Four</a>
 <a class="slide" href="#slide-5">Slide Five</a>
</nav>


<div class="carousel">
 <div class="slide-content" id="slide-1">
  <p>I'm Slide One</p>
 </div>

 <div class="slide-content" id="slide-2">
  <p>I'm Slide Two</p>
 </div>

 <div class="slide-content" id="slide-3">
  <p>I'm Slide Three</p>
 </div>

 <div class="slide-content" id="slide-4">
  <p>I'm Slide Four</p>
 </div>

 <div class="slide-content" id="slide-5">
  <p>I'm Slide Five</p>
 </div>
</div>


<script>

var utils = window.fizzyUIUtils;

var carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
var flkty = new Flickity( carousel, {
  prevNextButtons: false,
  pageDots: false,
  hash: true
});

// Elements
var cellsButtonGroup = document.querySelector('.tab-nav');
var cellsButtons = utils.makeArray( cellsButtonGroup.children );

// Update buttons on select
flkty.on( 'select', function() {
  var previousSelectedButton = cellsButtonGroup.querySelector('.is-selected');
  var selectedButton = cellsButtonGroup.children[ flkty.selectedIndex ];
  previousSelectedButton.classList.remove('is-selected');
  selectedButton.classList.add('is-selected');
});

// Cell select
cellsButtonGroup.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
  if ( !matchesSelector( event.target, '.slide' ) ) {
    return;
  }
  var index = cellsButtons.indexOf( event.target );
  flkty.select( index );
});
</script>
```

Comment: I dont know Flickity and hash script neither, but you could save the last `is-selected` to localStorage and then, on page load, try to use it...

Answer (score -2):

You can use localStorage to save the selector when the tab is clicked. At page load you can check for the last seleted tab in localStorage and set it active. It will definitely work for you if the user is refreshing the page. 
For handling back there are no such successfull methods you can rely on. You can turn off page cache in browser by adding `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate` header to your pages. If user goes back, the page will reload.

Comment: Please Define local storage on client side with javascript?

Comment: LocalStorage is a client side sorage where you can save data in key-value pairs. Please check this MDN Doc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Well you should put all this in your answer. I would not recommend using this but i guess for a carousel position it's ok.